# Why doesn't state_pressed work with custom view components?

Tags: android

I made a simple custom button class to test what is going on...

```
class TestButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

}
```

In the fragment xml I instatiate it like this...

```
<com.test.ui.components.TestButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mc_button_primary"
    android:text="doop"/>
```

mc_button_primary.xml defines a colored shape...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_rounded_radius"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/mc_button_primary_background_color"/>
</shape>
```

Finally, mc_button_primary_background_color.xml is a selector...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/ButtonAltBackgroundColor"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/ButtonDisabledBackgroundColor"
        android:state_enabled="false" />

    <item android:color="@color/ButtonBackgroundColor"/>

</selector>
```

It all looks fairly straight forward but the pressed state does not work! The strange thing is that if I change the fragment xml to just use the AppCompatButton...

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mc_button_primary"
    android:text="doop"/>
```

...it works perfectly! So my xml is not the problem. Its the custom class, which is about as bare bones as it gets. What am I missing?

Comment: You probably want the default value for `defStyleAttr` to be `androidx.appcompat.R.attr.buttonStyle`, not `0` (unless you were wanting to completely customize that, too). That default style will have `android:clickable` set to `true`, which will cause the `View`'s pressed state to be updated appropriately.

Comment: Thank you!! Ive been wracking my brain against that all day. Write that as an answer and Ill accept it as the answer.

Comment: Mike M. What should I use if the custom button is wrapped in a ViewGroup so that the super class of TestButton is ConstraintLayout? That is the case in my actual code, not the test.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm understanding your setup correctly. `ViewGroup`s in general usually aren't styleable, so they won't have a default style nor an attribute for one, so you could just use `0`. If you mean that you want the `ConstraintLayout` (subclass) to respond to presses, then you don't necessarily need a style for that; you can simply set `isClickable = true` in the constructor(s) or an `init` block. However, if you mean that you have another clickable `View` _inside_ that `ConstraintLayout`, that could get a little tricky, depending on what the desired behavior is.

Comment: The constraintLayout contains a clickable AppCompatButton which has the background set to that mc_button_primary.xml. Even when I set use the two argument constructor format it still doesnt respond to pressed color changes. It does call its onClick though

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're asking, but unless you need to customize the `ConstraintLayout` to make it styleable, then its `defStyleAttr` would just be `0`.

Comment: I should probably ask this in another question so I can show the details. Thanks for answering this one though